# Show that $\nabla\cdot\left(\dfrac{\mathbf{e}_r}{r^2}\right)=4\pi\delta(\mathbf{r})$ using the divergence theorem.

Tags: definite-integrals, intuition, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, surface-integrals

`The book answer goes as follows:`

> By the divergence theorem, in spherical coordinates we find $$\color{red}{\iiint_\limits{\large\text{volume}\,\tau}\nabla\cdot\left(\dfrac{\mathbf{e}_r}{r^2}\right)\mathrm{d}\tau}=\color{blue}{\iint_\limits{\large\text{surface enclosing}\, \tau}\dfrac{\mathbf{e}_r}{r^2}\cdot\mathbf{e}_r\,\mathrm{d}\sigma}=\color{#180}{\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{r^2}r^2\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi}=4\pi$$ Thus $\nabla\cdot\left(\dfrac{\mathbf{e}_r}{r^2}\right)$ has the properties that it is zero $\forall\,r\gt 0$ but its integral over any volume including the origin is $4\pi$; this suggests that it is equal to $4\pi\delta(\mathbf{r})$.

As mentioned in a comment below; $\mathbf{e}_r$ is a unit radial vector.

I know that the $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ and $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ integrals are a statement of the divergence theorem. The only thing I can't understand is how the $\color{#180}{\mathrm{green}}$ integral was obtained from the $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ integral.

I know that $$\mathrm{d}\sigma=\left|\frac{\partial  r}{\partial \theta}\times\frac{\partial r}{\partial \phi}\right|\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi\tag{1}$$ I think that equation $(1)$ has been used but I'm not sure how to use it. Could someone please explain how the $\color{#180}{\mathrm{green}}$ integral was reached?

Comment: $\boldsymbol{e}_r$ is the radial unit vector.

Comment: Additionally, $d\tau$ is the volume element. If the origin is taken to be surrounded by a sphere of radius $r$, then the surface element is $r^2do \boldsymbol{e}_r$, where do is the solid angle subtended at the origin by the surface element. It is simple to take $do = \sin\theta d\theta d\phi$.

Comment: The two conditions (the first provided by the divergence theorem and the second  that the integrand is zero for $r\neq 0$ are satisfied if we take the integrand to be $4\pi\delta (\vec r)$. That's all the author is saying and probably why he uses the word "suggests".

Comment: Using the parameterization given by spherical coordinates, when you compute $\vert \vec r_{\theta}\times \vec r_{\phi}\vert $ and substitute, you will get the green integrand. The limits are obtained by realizing you are integrating over a sphere of radius  r.

Comment: @Chilango Okay, can you please show me in an answer how to compute $\vert \vec r_{\theta}\times \vec r_{\phi}\vert$ and reach the $\color{#180}{\mathrm{green}}$ integral? Thank you.

Comment: Not much more I can give, that can aid you further than you already are on this - but I will say that **this question** in my (trivial) opinion anyway, is an example of a brilliantly constructed question. Well done BLAZE..

Comment: @Bacon I now have been given a superb answer by a user; which gave me the information necessary to give an answer of my own. I just thought I would let you know now that this question has been resolved. By the way, your opinion is far from trivial. Thanks again for your kind words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The surface integral can be evaluated in spherical coordinates:

1). Set

\begin{align}
x&=r\sin\theta\cos\phi\;,\\
y&=r\sin\theta\sin\phi\;,\\
z&=r\cos\theta\;,
\end{align}

2). Write

$\vec r(\theta,\phi)=r\sin\theta\cos\phi \vec i+r\sin\theta\sin\phi\vec j+r\cos\theta \vec k$

3). Then

$\vec r_{\theta}(\theta, \phi)=r\cos\theta\cos\phi \vec i+r\cos\theta\sin\phi\vec j-r\sin\theta \vec k$

and

$\vec r_{\phi}(\theta, \phi)=-r\sin\theta\sin\phi \vec i+r\sin\theta\cos\phi\vec j$

4). Find the magnitude of the cross product:

$\color{red}{\vert \vec r_{\phi}\times \vec r_{\theta}\vert =r^2\sin \theta.} $ $(\sin \theta \geq 0$ since $0\leq \theta <\pi)$,

so that

$d\sigma =r^2\sin \theta d\theta d\phi$.

5). Find the limits of integration:

$0\leq \phi <2\pi;\ 0\leq \theta <\pi$ because the surface is a sphere.

6). Substitute into the integral:

$\color{blue}{\iint_\limits{\large\text{surface enclosing}\, \tau}\dfrac{\mathbf{e}_r}{r^2}\cdot\mathbf{e}_r\,\mathrm{d}\sigma }=\int \int _{\sigma }\frac{1}{r^{2}}d\sigma =\int^{2\pi }_0 \int^{\pi }_0 \frac{1}{r^{2}}(r^{2}\sin \theta )d\theta d\phi=$

Comment: How did you deduce the part marked red in your answer?

Comment: I took the magnitude of the cross porduct. In general, fora parameterization $X(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$  it is easy to show that$dS=\sqrt{|X_u|^2 |X_v|^2 - (X_u \cdot X_v)^2} du dv$

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. I just needed to see some justification of the part marked $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ in your answer. I think that I understand now and have given an answer of my own. Kindest Regards.

Answer (score 2):

The vector $\vec r$ is a function of $\theta$ and $\phi$; which is given by $$\vec r=r\sin\theta\cos\phi \widehat i+r\sin\theta\sin\phi\widehat j+r\cos\theta \widehat k$$ and the unit vector $\widehat r$ is given by $$\color{teal}{\widehat  r=\sin\theta\cos\phi \widehat i+\sin\theta\sin\phi\widehat j+\cos\theta \widehat k}\tag{2}$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta}=r\cos\theta\cos\phi \widehat{i}+r\cos\theta\sin\phi\widehat{j}-r\sin\theta \widehat{k}$$
and 
$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial \phi}=-r\sin\theta\sin\phi \widehat i+r\sin\theta\cos\phi\widehat j$$

So $$\begin{align}\frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta}\times\frac{\partial r}{\partial \phi}&=\begin{vmatrix} \widehat i & \widehat j & \widehat k \\  r\cos\theta\cos\phi & r\cos\theta\sin\phi & -r\sin\theta \\ -r\sin\theta\sin\phi & r\sin\theta\cos\phi & 0 \end{vmatrix}\\&=r^2\sin^2\theta\cos\phi\widehat i +r^2\sin^2\theta\sin\phi\widehat j+ r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta\cos^2\phi\widehat k+r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta\sin^2\phi\widehat k\\&=r^2\sin^2\theta\cos\phi\widehat i +r^2\sin^2\theta\sin\phi\widehat j+ r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta\left(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi\right)\widehat k\\&=r^2{\left(\sin^2\theta\cos\phi\widehat i+\sin^2\theta\sin\phi\widehat j+\cos\theta\sin\theta\widehat k\right)}\\&=r^2\sin\theta\color{purple}{\underbrace{\left(\sin\theta\cos\phi\widehat i+\sin\theta\sin\phi\widehat j+\cos\theta\widehat k\right)}_{\color{teal}{\Large\text{From (2)}\,=\,\widehat r}}}\\&=r^2\sin\theta\,\widehat r\end{align}$$

Taking the magnitude gives $$\left|\frac{\partial  r}{\partial \theta}\times\frac{\partial r}{\partial \phi}\right|=\sqrt{\left(r^2\sin\theta\,\widehat r\right)^2}={\sqrt{r^4\sin^2\theta \,\widehat r^2}}=\underbrace{r^2\sin\theta}_{\Large\text{Since}\,\color{teal}{\widehat r}^2=1}$$
Therefore $$\color{#F80}{\mathrm{d}\sigma=\left|\frac{\partial  r}{\partial \theta}\times\frac{\partial r}{\partial \phi}\right|\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi}\tag{1}$$
$$=r^2\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi$$

As helpfully pointed out in a comment given by @Chilango we are integrating over a sphere of radius $r$. So the azimuthal angle $\phi$ has a limit range given by $0\leq \phi \lt 2\pi$ and the polar angle $\theta$ has a limit range given by $\ 0\leq \theta \lt\pi$.

Finally, substitution of $(1)$ and the limits into the $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ integral gives the $\color{#180}{\mathrm{green}}$ integral as required.

A special thanks goes to @Chilango for his/her answer that gave me the ideas necessary to give this answer with full justification that $$\left|\frac{\partial  r}{\partial \theta}\times\frac{\partial r}{\partial \phi}\right|=r^2\sin\theta$$

Answer (score 2):

A note on what I think to be a misleading trend in [some texts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632455/mathematical-meaning-of-certain-integrals-in-physics/1681370), where I have recently stumbled.

As a proper Riemann integral, $$\iiint_{\tau}\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\mathbf{e}_r}{r^2}\right)d\tau$$ where $\frac{\mathbf{e}_r}{r^2}=\frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^3}$ (it seems that $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{0}$ in your case), is $0$ if $\mathbf{y}\notin\bar{\tau}$ and does not exist if $\mathbf{y}\in\bar{\tau}$, because the integrand of a Riemann integral, in the usual calculus definitions of it, has to be defined on all the domain.

As the limit $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\iiint_{\tau\setminus B(\mathbf{y},\varepsilon)}\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^3}\right)dx_1dx_2dx_3$$ it is $0$ because $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}0=0$ and the same holds for the Lebesgue integral $$\int_{\tau}\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^3}\right)d\mu_{\mathbf{x}}$$which is calculated as the preceding limit.

This shows that, **under these definitions of the integral** and the usual definition of the derivative, **the divergence theorem**, certainly valid if, instead of $\frac{\mathbf{e}_r}{r^2}$ you had a vector field $\mathbf{F}\in C^1(\mathring{A})$ with $\tau\subset\mathring{A}$ satisfying opportune assumptions, **cannot be applied**.

Since $\forall\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{\mathbf{y}\}\quad\frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^3}=-\nabla\left(\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|}\right)$ and the divergence of the gradient is the Laplacian $\nabla\cdot\nabla=\nabla^2$, we see that $\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^3}\right)=-\nabla^2\left(\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|}\right)$. Then by reading the integral $$\int_{\tau}-\nabla^2\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)\varphi \,d\tau$$ where $\varphi\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ (typically $\varphi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)$) is such that $\forall\mathbf{x}\notin\tau\quad\varphi(\mathbf{x})=0$, in the symbolic way of the **Laplacian of the distribution** defined by $-\frac{1}{r}$, it can be shown, as it is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625017/diracs-delta-in-3-dimensions-proof-of-nabla2-boldsymbolx-boldsymbolx/1625086#1625086), that $-\int_{\tau}\nabla^2\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)\varphi \,d\tau=4\pi\int_{\tau}\delta_{\mathbf{y}}\varphi \,d\tau:=4\pi\varphi(\mathbf{y})$ (where $\delta_{\mathbf{y}}(\mathbf{x}):=\delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})$), but that is$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\iiint_{\tau\setminus B(\mathbf{y},\varepsilon)}\frac{-\nabla^2\varphi(\mathbf{x})}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|}dx_1dx_2dx_3=\int_{\tau}\frac{-\nabla^2\varphi(\mathbf{x})}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|}d\mu_{\mathbf{x}}$$if we use the usual Riemann (one th left) or Lebesgue (on the right) integrals, while $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\iiint_{\tau\setminus B(\mathbf{y},\varepsilon)}\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^3}\right)\varphi(\mathbf{x})dx_1dx_2dx_3=\int_{\tau}\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^3}\right)\varphi(\mathbf{x})d\mu_{\mathbf{x}}\equiv 0$$for all $\mathbf{y}$ and all functions $\varphi$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me; it is appreciated (+1)

Comment: It's a pleasure to share one's (little, in my case) knowledge!

Comment: Now that I have your attention maybe you could shed some light on [this simple question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693741/how-to-find-the-change-in-a-piecewise-derivative-of-a-function-at-a-given-point), best regards.

Comment: I see an answer has been given there. By the way, I have no idea what "change" means... if it means $\lim_{x\to x'^{+}}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} G-\lim_{x\to x'^{-}}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} G$, then your book's answer is quite trivial, but I'm not sure what it means...

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly the point, I have no idea what "change" means either, regards.

Comment: Any ideas on [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696600/how-to-find-legendre-polynomials)? Someone has already answered but they have failed to address the main issue in the question. Since you are good at explaining these things; Would you mind taking a look at it please? Thank you.

Comment: Honoured by your comment. I would be glad to help, but I only know (as you can see in my profile, I'm no expert) that as the very definition of the Legendre polynomials $P_n$: $$P_n(x):=\frac{1}{n!2^n}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$$because the textbook I've followed, Kolmogorov-Fomin's, defines them like that.